# could not find installable isam in asp

Tags: asp-classic

I want to insert data in to access database using asp code.When I m trying to do this internet explorer give me error i.e. "could not find installable isam"

```
    <html>
     <body>
     <%
        Dim conn
        set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;UID=;PWD="
        conn.Open "c:/webdata/northwind.mdb"
        Dim sql,str
        Response.Write("Hi")
        sql="INSERT INTO customers (customerID,companyname,"
        sql=sql & "contactname,address,city,postalcode,country)"
        sql=sql & " VALUES "
        sql=sql & "('" & Request.Form("custid") & "',"
        sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("compname") & "',"
        sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("contname") & "',"
        sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("address") & "',"
        sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("city") & "',"
        sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("postcode") & "',"
        sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("country") & "')"
        on error resume next
        conn.Execute sql,recaffected
        if err<>0 then
           Response.Write("No update permissions!")
        else
           Response.Write("<h3>" & recaffected & " record added</h3>")
        end if
        conn.close
    %>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that the Microsoft Data Access Components are not installed or are corrupted.

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-solve-could-not-find-installable-isam-errors.html

Download and install the latest MDAC:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5793

In this case I would say the problem is because you have UID and PWD in your provider statement.  Also the OleDb Jet provider uses User Id and Password instead of UID and PWD.

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
conn.Open "C:\webdata\northwind.mdb"
```

OR

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionString="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\webdata\northwind.mdb;User Id=;Password=;"
conn.Open
```

Comment: hi thanks for replaying it works fine but records are not stored in database when i submit it. it goes into if condition in my codeif err<>0 then
           Response.Write("No update permissions!")
        else
           Response.Write("<h3>" & recaffected & " record added</h3>")
        end if

Comment: You have error handling turned on with the `on error resume next`.  I would assume that the Microsoft Access database is not writable by IIS.